# Grails GORM query for null hasOne association fails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I use Grails 2.2.4 (same behaviour in Grails 2.3.11) and have a domain class A that references a domain class B

```
class A {
    static hasOne = [b: B]

    static constraints = { b nullable: true }
}

class B {
    static belongsTo = [a: A]
}
```

I try to find all instances of A that have a B.

```
A.findAllByBIsNotNull()*.b
```

returns a list of Bs and nulls:

```
[null, null, b1, b2, null, ...]
```

How so?

Same happens if I use

```
A.withCriteria {
    isNotNull 'b'
}*.b
```

What do I do wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I realized that the problem is because of the `hasOne`. If instead of `static hasOne = [b: B]`, there is `B b`, it works. The former moves the foreign key to table B, the latter creates the foreign key relation in table A.
So why does the querying not work in the former case and how can I query for all `A`s, not having a `B` when the foreign key is within B?

Comment: what happens if you call `println A.findAllByBIsNotNull()*.b*.id` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved it, thanks to the comment of @Koloritnij and the modified answer of @Alexander Suraphel.
Thanks for that.

If the foreign key is on the `B` table (due to the `hasOne`), the following two queries solve the case:

**finding all `A`s with `B`s: (`b` is not `null`):**

```
A.withCriteria {
  b {}
}
```

This results in an inner join: `SELECT * FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.a_id;`

**finding all `A`s *without* `B`s (`b` is `null`):**

```
A.withCriteria {
  createAlias('b', 'bAlias', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
  isNull 'bAlias.id'
}
```

This results in a left outer join: `SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id=b.a_id WHERE b.id IS NULL;`

Comment: .+1 for answering your question! Consider upvoting and/or accepting the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Following UPDATE:**

Use one of the fields in `B`. Let's say `B` has the field `name`:

`A.withCriteria { b { isNotNull("name") }}*.b`

**Old Answer:**

The problem could be in the `toString()` of Class B.

Add

```
String toString() { 
    getClass().name
}
```

to Class `B` and try running your query again.

Comment: Very creative, but no. Java implements default `toString` in a proper way. And Groovy does not change that.

Answer (score 1):

Also for future reference, anyone looking to do the same but with GORM Where queries or DetachedCriteria, the equivalent would be as follows:

```
def criteria = new DetachedCriteria(A)
criteria.where {
    join('b', JoinType.LEFT)
    b {
        isNull 'id'
    }
}.list()
```

Answer (score 0):

If u need only to take B, why u can't use:

```
B.findAll()
```

or if by A:

```
 B.findAllByA(a)
```

**UPD:**
Use criteria:

```
    A.createCriteria().list{
       isNotNull 'B'
       isNull 'C'
    }
```

Or this is bad idea but must work:

```
def bList = B.createCriteria().list{
    projections{
       property 'id'
    }
    A.createCriteria().list{
      b{
       'in' ('id',bList)
      }
    }
```

Comment: The example is a simplified case. What I actually want to is 
`A.findAllByBIsNotNullAndCIsNull()` and then go through all the `A`s.

Comment: `A.createCriteria().list { isNotNull 'b' }*.b` returns `[null, null, null, ...]`.

Comment: A.createCriterya().list{b{isNotNull 'id'}}*.b this is my last idea

Comment: That indeed solves it! It results in an inner join of `A` and `B` and thus only returns A with a B. Unfortunately, there is no way to query for all `A`s without a `B`. I need to do this as well...

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't that be
`A.findAllBybIsNotNull()*.b` (note lower case b) ?

Or

`A.findAll("from A as a where a.b is null")`

Comment: B should be upper case (see examples in http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/GORM.html#finders, e.g. String title -> findByTitle...)

`A.findAll("from A as a where a.b is null")*.b` returns an empty list.

`A.findAll("from A as a where a.b is not null")*.b` returns a list with nulls and non-nulls.