# Left Join grails criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

we have a User class

```
class User {
...
}
```

and another class:

```
class Licence {

    User user
    Event event

}
```

What we want to do is the Left Join (because not for every user we have an entry in the licence class).

We naively did this:

```
def a = User.withCriteria {

    createAlias("Licence", "l", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    eq("id", "l.user.id")

    if (something == true)
        isNull("l.id")
    else
        isNotNull("l.id")
}
```

But the query fails with:

```
could not resolve property Licence of User
```

Can somebody help how to do this query?

Comment: What is a nature of the connection between `User` and `Licence`? Is it a OneToMany or OneToOne? It seems to me that you need `static hasOne = [licence: Licence]` or `static hasMany = [licences: Licence]` in User

Comment: actually it is a one-to-one on the user. But I have not declared a hasOne relationship becuase I always had a problem with a hasOne when the hasOne side can be null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that grails is not aware of the connection on the `User` side if you do not have a foreign key or at least `hasOne`. If you had `static hasOne = [licence: Licence]` your code would work as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110152/grails-gorm-query-for-null-hasone-association-fails).

Comment: not quite right. In the Licence class, there are 2 foreign keys: user and event

Comment: I meant: you need to have a foreign key (Licence licence) or hasOne (licence) in the User class for the criteria in question to work